# An IBOutlet is not initiated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, custom-cell

I'm trying to make a tableview with customized cells.

I've created 2 files .m and .h that refer to my class CustomCell.
Here is the code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *miniLogo;
    IBOutlet UILabel *cellText;
    IBOutlet UIButton *deleteButton;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *miniLogo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *deleteButton;

@end

-------------------------------------------------------------

#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell


@synthesize miniLogo,cellText, deleteButton;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

/*
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}*/

@end
```

With a .xib file, i've designed my cell, and connected the IBOutlets and set the Identifier for the cell.

In the table with my customized cells, I call the cells in the method tableView:cellForRowAtOndexPath: like this :

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellsIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil){
        UIViewController *tempVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (CustomCell *)tempVC.view;
    }
```

When I launch my app, the labels display the texts set, and the image views show the right images. But the buttons don't appear. In fact, when setting break points, I seen that address for my buttons are always 0x00000000 (means that my buttons aren't initiated).

Can someone help me to solve this problem please.

Comment: Are you sure you have connected the deleteButton outlet in your IB?

Comment: Take them out of the interface. You don't need them being both synthensized and autosynthesized

Comment: My button is well connected to my .h file.
I've deleted my IBOutlet in the interface, but no changes....

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem.

In he viewDidLoad I was doing :

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"myCells" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellsIdentifier];
```

But because I have changed my .xib name, I wasn't loading the right interface.
What is strange is that I don't have any nib named "myCells".
Maybe I should have perform a "clean"  on my project...